# JavaScript - How to create random longitude and latitudes?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create random longitude and latitudes.  I need to create numbers between 
-180.000 and +180.000.  So, I might get 101.325 or -3.546 or -179.561.

Can you tell me a quick formula for that?

Thanks to everyone for your help. I have combined a couple of examples to suit my needs.  Yes, I could shorten the code, but this really helps to see what's going on.

```
// LONGITUDE -180 to + 180
function generateRandomLong() {
    var num = (Math.random()*180).toFixed(3);
    var posorneg = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if (posorneg == 0) {
        num = num * -1;
    }
    return num;
}
// LATITUDE -90 to +90
function generateRandomLat() {
    var num = (Math.random()*90).toFixed(3);
    var posorneg = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if (posorneg == 0) {
        num = num * -1;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: I really like a couple of the answers I got. I am not a math genius or a JavaScript genius either, so I really needed some good examples for my specific purposes.  I'll post my modified code in a second.  Thanks to everyone who answered my question.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

```
function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed) * 1;
    // .toFixed() returns string, so ' * 1' is a trick to convert to number
}
```

In your case: `getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3)`:

```
12.693
-164.602
-7.076
-37.286
52.347
-160.839
```

Comment: Yes, this is a really efficient solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Just what I'm looking for. Thanks! "DotNet Ninja"? You look like a "DotJavascript Ninja" as well.

Comment: The OP did ask for a "quick formula", so this is probably fine, but note that it suffers from an easily overlooked bias towards points near the poles.  See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html for an explanation of the problem and alternative approaches that, admittedly, wouldn't be nearly as "quick".

Comment: To clarify, the issue would be with using this function the way that the OP intended, rather than an issue with the function itself.

Comment: VERY Well Done!

Answer (score 8):

```
Math.random()*360 - 180
```

that will get you a range of -180 to 180

And if you really only want 3 decimal places

```
Math.round((Math.random()*360 - 180) * 1000)/1000
```

Comment: `.toFixed(3)` is a nicer way to round the number to 3 decimal places

Comment: @Gareth eh... have to convert back to number and it only truncates... not a big deal but I prefer simple math

Comment: True, I forgot that returns a string. But it does round properly.

Comment: @Joseph, look at my answer. It uses `.toFixed()` and returns number. The magic is in `*1`

Answer (score 2):

```
function generateRandomLatLng()
{
    var num = Math.random()*180;
    var posorneg = Math.floor(Math.random());
    if (posorneg == 0)
    {
        num = num * -1;
    }
    return num;
}
```

Comment: I liked your solution very much. I did realize thought that longitude and latitude have different ranges, not just -180 to +180, so I had to modify my question and -- necessarily -- the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Math.random() * 360 - 180
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I made that does this:

```
function Rand(x, y){
    //Returns a random number between 0 and X if Y is undefined
    //Returns a random number between X and Y if Y is defined

    return x+(Math.random()*(y-x)) || Math.random()*x;
}
```

This works with integers as well as floats.

Answer (score -1):

In kotlin:

```
import kotlin.random.Random

fun getRandomLatitude(): Double {
    return Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble(-90.0, 90.0)
}

fun getRandomLongitude(): Double {
   return Random(System.currentTimeMillis()).nextDouble(-180.0, 180.0)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try http://www.geomidpoint.com/random/

**Features:**

- Random Location in Circular region - centred at the starting point
- Random Location in Rectangular region - north, south, west and east
  limits
- Retrieve Locations in different formates like csv and json

Comment: This method does not address a coding solution, instead it references the use of an application.