# Generate random Google Maps street view coordinates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

I am using the Google Maps API for JavaScript. 
How can I generate valid random street view coordinates?
Is there any API default method or I must write my own method and how can I do that?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think you can get a street view by using lat and long coordinates. This person explains how to randomly generate lat and long coordinates -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/6878845/8085668

Comment: This sounds simple? Create 2 sets of valid values for longitude and latitude and randomly sample from each for your destination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streetview is only available in some locations, so not every lat/lng pair will be a valid location for a Streetview Panorama. No problem - StreetviewService to the rescue!

Generate a random lat/lng, and then check if there is a valid Panorama at that location using StreetviewService. If not, try another location.

It's worth noting that a LOT of the Earth's surface has no Street View data, so you may want to pick random numbers within a smaller area - e.g. the bounds of the United States, rather than risking landing in the Ocean again and again.

```
function TryRandomLocation(callback) {
  var lat = (Math.random() * 90) - 90;
  var lng = (Math.random() * 180) - 180;
  var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

  // Try to find a panorama within 50 metres 
  sv.getPanorama({
      location: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      radius: 50
  }, callback);
}

function HandleCallback(data, status) {
    if (status == 'OK') {
      // Call your code to display the panorama here.
    } else {
      // Nothing here! Let's try another location.
      TryRandomLocation(HandleCallback);
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
  TryRandomPanorama(HandleCallback);
}
```