# How to zoom a Google map to a percentage of markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps

It's fairly straight-forward to zoom a Google map bounds to all of the markers.

```
var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
bounds.extend(position);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

What I'd like to do is dynamically zoom a Google map bounds to a percentage of the markers.

For example if there is a map with a number of outlying markers I'd like to zoom the bounds to 70% of the markers.

I could do this programmatically by looping through all of the markers, identifying the 70% which are closest to each other & setting the bounds around them. (If I go down this route I'll post the code up).

But I wondered if there's existing functionality that allows for this behaviour.

Comment: i did something like this in here Maps but rather I extended the bounds by a percentage  - so bounds plus 10%.  you could do the reverse of that by using the bounds rectangle and reducing it but the remainder & of maybe 30%. then set that result as your bounds.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment - why not take the bounds of your markers then reduce that by 30%.

You can use the getNorthEast() and getSouthWest() functions on the bounds object and reduce those coordinates by the required amount then re create a new bounds object. with the result.

This is what I did to increase it by 10%.  You can do something similar to reduce it by 30%;

```
var increasePercentage = 1.10;  //10%
var pointSouthWest = markerBounds.getSouthWest();
var latAdjustment = (pointNorthEast.lat() - pointSouthWest.lat()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
var lngAdjustment = (pointNorthEast.lng() - pointSouthWest.lng()) * (increasePercentage - 1);
var newPointNorthEast = new google.maps.LatLng(pointNorthEast.lat() + latAdjustment, pointNorthEast.lng() + lngAdjustment);
var newPointSouthWest = new google.maps.LatLng(pointSouthWest.lat() - latAdjustment, pointSouthWest.lng() - lngAdjustment);

bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(newPointNorthEast);
bounds.extend(newPointSouthWest);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

google.maps.LatLngBounds documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/3/coordinates#LatLngBounds

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach - working example at: https://jsfiddle.net/BaronGrivet/dm4Lhzg6/26/

```
var map;
var markers = [];
var bounds = [];
var centreLat = 37.422000;
var centreLng = -122.084057;

$(document).ready(initMap());

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: centreLat,
            lng: centreLng
        },
        zoom: 1,
        disableDefaultUI: true
        });

        for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) { 
        var lat = getRandomInRange(-45, 45, 3);
        var lng = getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 3);
        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

        markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: position,
        map: map,
        icon: 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png'
      });
      markers[i].distance = distanceBetween(lat, lng, centreLat, centreLng);    
        }

}

function zoomMapToMarkers(percent) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var numberOfMarkers = parseInt(markers.length * (percent / 100));
    markers.sort(compareDistance);
    markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        if (numberOfMarkers > 0) {
            bounds.extend(marker.position);
            marker.setIcon( 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png');
            numberOfMarkers--;
        } else {
            marker.setIcon( 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');

        }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

function distanceBetween(lat1, lng1, lat2, lng2) {
    var lat = lat1 - lat2;
    var lng = lng1 - lng2;
    return Math.sqrt(lat * lat + lng * lng);
}

function compareDistance(a, b) {
    if (a.distance < b.distance)
        return -1;
    if (a.distance > b.distance)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}



//From https://stackoverflow.com/a/6878845/348485
function getRandomInRange(from, to, fixed) {
    return (Math.random() * (to - from) + from).toFixed(fixed) * 1;
    // .toFixed() returns string, so ' * 1' is a trick to convert to number
}
```